# custom error handling in typescript express?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, asynchronous, error-handling

Okay so i have been using javascript to build my APIs for a long time, i decided to start using typescript and as you can imagine, i keep running into errors. I have a custom error handler for when a route isnt found as seen below.

```
import express, {Response, Request } from 'express'
const notFoundErrorHandler = (err: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => res.status(404).send('Route does not exist')

export = notFoundErrorHandler
```

then this is what my app.ts looks like:

```
import express from 'express'
import 'express-async-errors';
const app = express()

import notFoundErrorHandler = require('./middleware/not-found')

app.use(notFoundErrorHandler);

app.get('/hi', (req, res) => {
    res.send('HIIIIIIII')
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`app is listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`)
})
```

The above code works in javascript, as long as i import 'express-async-errors', however in typescript i keep getting this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(err: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction)' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PathParams'.
```

when i tried to run ''npm i --save-dev @types/express-async-errors'' in the console, i also got an error:

```
404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fexpress-async-errors - Not found
'@types/express-async-errors@*' is not in this registry.
```

Can anyone please tell me whats wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: @eekinci if you dont mind, do you mind assisting with an example, i adjusted the code to match (err, req, res, next) type but the error now is basically the same

Answer (score 0):

You should import your `notFoundErrorHandler` with:

```
import notFoundErrorHandler from './middleware/not-found'
```

**express-async-errors**

And `@types/express-async-errors` does not exist - But `express-async-errors` works with typescript, as described here: [Not working with typescript](https://github.com/davidbanham/express-async-errors/issues/33)

```
import "express-async-errors";
// works perfectly fine for me in TS, ,maybe that is your fix?
```

**middleware.ts**

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

export function notFoundHandler(req: Request, res: Response) {
  res.status(404).send('Route does not exist');
}
```

**index.ts**

```
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
import 'express-async-errors';
import { notFoundHandler } from './middleware';

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/hi', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send(req.path);
});

app.use(notFoundHandler);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`app is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

---

**Result**

- http://localhost:3000/hi

  `/hi`
- http://localhost:3000/

  `Route does not exist`

Comment: i really thank you for your response, it seems like it is working perfectly fine for you, however after copying exactly the same code, it is still bringing up the error. I am thinking there must be something fundamentally wrong with the way i set up the project. I am honestly out of options cause ive tried everything, i will try to set up the project again and try again. Thanks again for your input.